# Mysql - How to Join all the names that has the same value and transform into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So i have this table in mysql

```
      Table  - My_table
     ----------------------

    Name      GameAccount
    peter     peterGamer
    peter     peter2
    peter     petergaming
```

what I want to do is to join all the names that has the same value and transform into only one.
How can i achieve that ?

```
example :   

Name        GameAccounts
peter       peterGamer 
            peter2
            peterGaming
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single row, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
select name, group_concat(gameaccount separator ' ') as gameaccounts
from my_table t
group by name;
```

You can adjust the separate to be what you want.  The default is a comma.

Comment: and if i want all the table ?  select *from would work ?